# Query without using except

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got these tables and values:

```
create table Instrument (
  instrumentnaam       varchar(14)          not null,
  toonhoogte           varchar(7)           not null
)

INSERT INTO instrument VALUES ('piano',    ''       );
INSERT INTO instrument VALUES ('fluit',    ''       );
INSERT INTO instrument VALUES ('fluit',    'alt'    );
INSERT INTO instrument VALUES ('saxofoon', 'alt'    );
INSERT INTO instrument VALUES ('saxofoon', 'tenor'  );
INSERT INTO instrument VALUES ('saxofoon', 'sopraan');
INSERT INTO instrument VALUES ('gitaar',   ''       );
INSERT INTO instrument VALUES ('viool',    ''       );
INSERT INTO instrument VALUES ('viool',    'alt'    );
INSERT INTO instrument VALUES ('drums',    ''       );

create table Bezettingsregel (
   stuknr               numeric(5)           not null,
   instrumentnaam       varchar(14)          not null,
   toonhoogte           varchar(7)           not null,
   aantal               numeric(2)           not null
)

INSERT INTO bezettingsregel VALUES ( 2, 'drums',    '',      1);
INSERT INTO bezettingsregel VALUES ( 2, 'saxofoon', 'alt',   2);
INSERT INTO bezettingsregel VALUES ( 2, 'saxofoon', 'tenor', 1);
INSERT INTO bezettingsregel VALUES ( 2, 'piano',    '',      1);
INSERT INTO bezettingsregel VALUES ( 3, 'fluit',    '',      1);
INSERT INTO bezettingsregel VALUES ( 5, 'fluit',    '',      3);
INSERT INTO bezettingsregel VALUES ( 9, 'fluit',    '',      1);
INSERT INTO bezettingsregel VALUES ( 9, 'fluit',    'alt',   1);
INSERT INTO bezettingsregel VALUES ( 9, 'piano',    '',      1);
INSERT INTO bezettingsregel VALUES (12, 'piano',    '',      1);
INSERT INTO bezettingsregel VALUES (12, 'fluit',    '',      2);
INSERT INTO bezettingsregel VALUES (13, 'drums',    '',      1);
INSERT INTO bezettingsregel VALUES (13, 'saxofoon', 'alt',   1);
INSERT INTO bezettingsregel VALUES (13, 'saxofoon', 'tenor', 1);
INSERT INTO bezettingsregel VALUES (13, 'fluit',    '',      2);
INSERT INTO bezettingsregel VALUES (14, 'piano',    '',      1);
INSERT INTO bezettingsregel VALUES (14, 'fluit',    '',      1);
INSERT INTO bezettingsregel VALUES (15, 'saxofoon', 'alt',   2);
INSERT INTO bezettingsregel VALUES (15, 'fluit',    'alt',   2);
INSERT INTO bezettingsregel VALUES (15, 'piano',    '',      1);

create table Stuk (
   stuknr               numeric(5)           not null,
   componistId          numeric(4)           not null,
   titel                varchar(20)          not null,
   stuknrOrigineel      numeric(5)           null,
   genrenaam            varchar(10)          not null,
   niveaucode           char(1)              null,
   speelduur            numeric(3,1)         null,
   jaartal              numeric(4)           not null
)

INSERT INTO stuk VALUES ( 1,  1, 'Blue bird',       NULL, 'jazz',     NULL, 4.5,  1954);
INSERT INTO stuk VALUES ( 2,  2, 'Blue bird',       1,    'jazz',     'B',  4,    1988);
INSERT INTO stuk VALUES ( 3,  4, 'Air pur charmer', NULL, 'klassiek', 'B',  4.5,  1953);
INSERT INTO stuk VALUES ( 5,  5, 'Lina',            NULL, 'klassiek', 'B',  5,    1979);
INSERT INTO stuk VALUES ( 8,  8, 'Berceuse',        NULL, 'klassiek', NULL, 4,    1786);
INSERT INTO stuk VALUES ( 9,  2, 'Cradle song',     8,    'klassiek', 'B',  3.5,  1990);
INSERT INTO stuk VALUES (10,  8, 'Non piu andrai',  NULL, 'klassiek', NULL, NULL, 1791);
INSERT INTO stuk VALUES (12,  9, 'I''ll never go',  10,   'pop',      'A',  6,    1996);
INSERT INTO stuk VALUES (13, 10, 'Swinging Lina',   5,    'jazz',     'B',  8,    1997);
INSERT INTO stuk VALUES (14,  5, 'Little Lina',     5,    'klassiek', 'A',  4.3,  1998);
INSERT INTO stuk VALUES (15, 10, 'Blue sky',        1,    'jazz',     'A',  4,    1998);
```

Now i want write a query that show the instruments that are using in the genre 'klassiek' but NOT in the genre 'jazz'. I need to do this without using EXCEPT

This is my attempt:

```
SELECT i.instrumentnaam
FROM instrument i inner join 
bezettingsregel b on i.instrumentnaam = b.instrumentnaam 
inner join stuk s on b.stuknr = s.stuknr
WHERE genrenaam = 'klassiek'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT stuknr
                  FROM stuk
                  WHERE genrenaam = 'jazz'
                 )
```

I can't figure it out. Thanx for help!

Comment: Are you perhaps a student? I have the exact same tables and stuff on my laptop for school.

Comment: Yes, i am preparing for tomorrow

Comment: Nice, I'm from the HAN as well. Big test coming up, huh?

Comment: Haha thats right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `group by` and `having`.  Here is one method:

```
SELECT b.instrumentnaam
FROM bezettingsregel b inner join
     stuk s
     on b.stuknr = s.stuknr
WHERE s.genrenaam IN ('klassiek', 'jazz')
GROUP BY b.instrumentnaam
HAVING MAX(s.genrenaam) = 'klassiek' AND MIN(s.genrenaam) = 'klassiek';
```

Note:  You don't need `Instrument` because you have the name in `bezettingsregel`.

Comment: Thanx for the answer, What i don't understand is the using of max and min in this situation can you explain this?

Comment: @Yakalent . . . It is just checking that the value is always `'klassiek'` and never `'jazz'`.  There are other ways, but this way is pretty simple.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Gordon Linoff (+1) is much simpler in comparison, but here is how you would use `not exists()` to do what you want:

```
select distinct b.instrumentnaam
from bezettingsregel b 
  inner join stuk s 
    on b.stuknr = s.stuknr
where s.genrenaam = 'klassiek'
 and not exists (
  select 1
  from stuk nes
    inner join bezettingsregel neb 
      on neb.stuknr = nes.stuknr
  where nes.genrenaam = 'jazz'
   and neb.instrumentnaam = b.instrumentnaam
  )
```

And here is how you could do it with `instrumentnaam not in()`

```
select distinct b.instrumentnaam
from bezettingsregel b 
  inner join stuk s 
    on b.stuknr = s.stuknr
where s.genrenaam = 'klassiek'
 and b.instrumentnaam not in (
  select instrumentnaam
  from stuk nes
    inner join bezettingsregel neb 
      on neb.stuknr = nes.stuknr
  where nes.genrenaam = 'jazz'
  )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/YGJEJ76277